# CSS only for IE8 compataible mode in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have a question.
I have to change css on my website. All works on IE11 and IE8, but I must do any workaround to use IE8 in compatible mode in IE11. I guess  use other css to change position of elements, but I dont know how to use it. No problem is for IE8 or IE11 only. But problem is between IE8 and IE8 compatible mode.

What can I do ?

Comment: to get it working in IE8 and below, put this in the header `<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to-your-css/file.css"><![endif]-->` and in that `.css` put your CSS fixes

Comment: make sure to include the above AFTER you include your main `css` file, use same css rules names for rules which contain fixes only

Comment: Yea i know, but problem is  between IE8 and IE8 in emulation on IE11 - On IE8 all works fine, but on emulation doesn't.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't understand your question first

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using JavaScript, then you can detect IE11 by using:

```
if (document.documentMode == 8) { 
    var jscriptVer = Function('return /*@cc_on @_jscript_version@*/;')();
    var is8on11 = jscriptVer == 11;
    if (is8on11) {
        document.documentElement.className += ' is-ie8-on-ie11'
    }
}
```

Keep the Function (so that required comment is not removed by compression). Don't change with the code or comment in the function (written that way to avoids some quirks in versions of IE).

You can then use CSS to override a rule like:

```
html.is-ie8-on-ie11 .some-target-class {
    width: 20px;
}
```